# Multiple on clause using codeigniter active record

Tags: codeigniter, left-join, on-clause

I need to do a multiple on clause on a left join query using codeigniter active record.
I write this code:

```
$this->db->join('table1', 'table1.col1 = table2.id', 'left');
$this->db->where_not_in('table.col2', $list);
```

by doing this codeigniter add where not in clause, while I need to add a ON clause, related to the left join.
If it's possible I would like to use active records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->join('table1', 'table1.col1 = table2.id AND col2 NOT IN ('.implode(',', $list).')', 'left');
```